# Push notifications with nodejs+Mysql+Onesignal

Tags: mysql, node.js, onesignal

I want to use push notifications as breaking news to my mobile application, everything works perfect but the problem is i need to push a notification whenever database gets new headline. If i use pooling with set interval it continuously  checking and sending same notification again and again . i try with mysql triggers with datetime change but its not working as expected.

what is alternative for listening database changes if row get updates then i must send notification. what i did till now something like this.

```
connection.query("select headline from news_d inner join werte_inc W where datum = (W.bezugsdatum)", function (err, notifydata) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error handling")
    }
    else {

        var newsnotification = notifydata[0].headline;
        var sendNotification = function (data) {
            var headers = {
                .....
            };

        sendNotification(newsnotification);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have standard MySQL database technology available to you, you have no choice but to *poll* your database looking for changes to push to your clients. Many systems work this way. The trick is to make your polling query as cheap as possible, so running it every few seconds doesn't bring your system to its knees.

Something like this sequence of queries usually does the trick for polling. Every time you use it, you make a record of when it was used. You need indexes on both datestamp columns to make this fast.

```
 select @recent:= MAX(poll_datestamp), @now:=NOW() FROM poll_record;
 select id from news_d where post_date > @recent and post_date <= @now;
 insert into poll_record (poll_datestamp) values (@now);
```

Only if you get some records back from `select id ...` do you bother to retrieve the entire result set. But you still have to run these queries multiple times a minute to send your push notifications with low latency.

This code avoids race conditions by always searching for items in the time range `(@recent, @now]`.

A second approach, more complex, but far better for realtime: Use a message queuing system like RabbitMQ or AWS's queuing system. Get the code that writes your news items into your database also to send messages. Get your push-notification software to consume those messages and send the push notifications. There are plenty of tutorials on the topic on the toobz. Here's one. https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-19-part2-2-rabbitmq-for-beginners_example-and-sample-code-node-js.html

A variant on that approach: There's an addin for MySQL that lets you send messages from a trigger into a message queuing system. https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_stomp If you control your MySQL server machine, you might consider using this to originate your messages.

You'll need to occasionally clean up your `poll_record` table something like this

```
  DELETE FROM poll_record WHERE poll_datestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Comment: Thanks for your great ideas i have just found this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events) and its working fine in localhost. i need to check it in my remote server. Is it effect my database with these type of libraries.